# is a animal more responsible then a child? if yes why?

Tags: minor-katan-child, capital-punishment, murder

if an animal kills a Jew it deserves the death penalty [source](https://www.chabad.org/682975/)

if a child (under 13/12) kills a Jew he is completely free (no consequences)?
if yes why?

Comment: Maybe because we don't have the same value for an animal life then for human life...

Comment: @mroll but an adult(sane) human gets the death penalty

Comment: @hazoriz Not if he didn’t mean to. And a child, who doesn’t have intent, is automatically considered not on purpose. A cow also doesn’t have intent - but we don’t care about animal life when it leads to endangering human life. Feel free to sic PETA on me for that.

Comment: @DonielF from halacha 9 in the above source **"animal that kills [a person] is not stoned to death unless it had the intent** to kill a person for whom it would be executed" and from halacha 2 here https://www.chabad.org/1172728/ "Cases involving **capital punishment** may not be judged by a court with less than **23 judges,** i.e., a minor Sanhedrin. This applies not only to instances where humans are judged with regard to capital punishment, but **also when animals face such judgment.** " (btw i am not a vegitarian)

Comment: @hazoriz (Meant the PETA thing as a joke.) I think intent by animals is defined as did it look at a person and start charging them, or was it just walking along and accidentally stepped on a person (latter case would seem to be Regel and therefore liable for damage but not to the death penalty; former case is Keren). When an animal gets killed it’s going to be judged by a court of 23 only because it’s being killed - but do you seriously think that the animal needs eidim and hasra’ah before they can do so?

Comment: @DonielF i think it needs eidim (but not hasroa) search for כשיש עדים בדבר here https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=34152 , but maybe not since by a ben-noach 1 witness is enough, btw a koton can also have intent as an animal

Comment: @hazoriz You can kill a Katan HaRodef, sure, but I don’t think you can kill him once he’s done the deed.

Answer (score 4):

The [Ramban (BERAISHIS 9:5)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ramban_on_Genesis.9.5?lang=he) says that an animal  which kills a person does not receive death as a punishment because animals do not get rewarded or punished for their actions (as they have no Bechira (free will)). He goes on to say that it is a special *Gezairas Hamelech* decree from the King Hashem that an animal which kills a person gets stoned. A child which does not receive punishment for his actions and there is no specific decree that he is put to death therefore is not killed for killing another person.