# What is a child held responsible for?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah, minor-katan-child, age

Related [is a animal more responsible then a child? if yes why?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93071/is-a-animal-more-responsible-then-a-child-if-yes-why)

Tangentially, to a statement made in this question: [At what age is a Ben Noach responsible to perform his "mitzvot"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109206/at-what-age-is-a-ben-noach-responsible-to-perform-his-mitzvot)

A child before the age of adulthood (codified as 12/13, depending on gender) is not required to perform certain mitzvot, and is not held accountable for breaking some or not fulfilling some. Is this status as "child" an across-the-board one which absolves the child of ALL mitzvot? Is there a list of mitzvot that a child at any particular age or level of education is required to perform or observe, or be held accountable for, not the parent?

I have heard that under three years old also makes a difference in certain actions, and that a child "who understands the laws and his actions" is also held accountable in certain cases, but I don't know where to find a hard and fast rule about the particulars -- ages, defining features, types of mitzvot.

As a side note, the tag for "minor-katan-child" reads "Children of this age are minors **with respect to various rules**, including the obligation to fulfill mitzvos (God's commands)" (emphasis mine) -- is there a list of those "various rules"?

Comment: "is not required to perform certain mitzvot". Children are exempt from all *mitzvos*. Do you mean Rabbinically?

Comment: I mean on all levels and by different levels of authority -- can an eleven year old intentionally eat treif and be totally absolved? What about keeping shabbos? Does a child therefore, not get any schar for what he does?

Comment: @rosends a child is never held accountable! Under three his father has to stop him.  A child never has an obligation his father has.

Comment: Related (and possibly duplicate. The focus of the question is about Bein Adam L'Chavero, but the answers are more generic): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117373/is-one-obligated-to-do-teshuva-for-transgressions-between-man-and-his-fellow-c~

Comment: Note that I believe the obligation of keeping Nedarim actually start a year earlier (11 for a girl, 12 for a boy), if that counts as a valid answer for your question.

Comment: @Salmononius2 that would certainly be helpful. I also stumbled on a discussion about hitting one's parents that refers to age 8, but I didn't really read through it to know if that points to anything normative.

Comment: @robev I found this https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/36105 discussion -- please look at the two paragraphs under "Children" and note the shift in language which seems to say that there is an obligation on the child (right after saying that the obligation is on the father).

Comment: @interested this discussion https://jewishvues.com/articles/kiddush-hashem/ mentions an obligation on a child (3rd paragraph).

Comment: This source https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/who-is-obligated/ says that a child is obligated in tzitzis at age three. Is this an obligation with no consequence?

Comment: Another source mentons different levels of chiyuv miderobonon on a child in terms of megillah https://dinonline.org/2013/02/23/children-and-the-mitzvos-of-purim/

Comment: @rosends I skimmed through 3 of the links you brought, and didn't see anything that pointed to the child having an obligation to specifically do the Mitzvah, beyond Chinuch (which is an obligation on the parent) or incidental reasons to do the Mitzvah.

Comment: Can't remember where I saw it, but I think there is a Rema that a child can be held accountable בידי שמים for things that he is advanced enough to understand that they are wrong. The hard-and-fast rule of 13 years old etc. is for beis din, not for the heavenly court.

Comment: I see that some bring evidence from the story of Shmuel in Berachos 31b, where little Shmuel seems to have been held responsible in the eyes of heaven, at the tender age of two! He must have been very mature.

Comment: @MichoelR a statement like that, sourced, would be a great find!

Comment: Found this Maharsha there https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Berakhot.31b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: I am not quoting him on this, but I once heard the idea from R' Tzvi Berkowitz shlit"a regarding a different din: מתנוונה, Sotah 6a. He explained that the Sotah trial has aspects of din shamayim, and therefore it was possible (according to רבי) that it could take zechuyos into account - something that a human court cannot. Dinei shamayim can be more flexible.

Comment: @MichoelR is there an explicit statement of the status of na'ar which has the pre-13 year old responsible for certain laws?

Comment: I'd like to find that Rema I imagine I remember.

Comment: Asked R' Berkowitz, pointed me to OH 343 https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.343?lang=bi Interesting.

Comment: The Rema there points to Yoreh Deah 241, where the Darchei Moshe says a little more. I think it significantly waters down what I was claiming, but definitely doesn't eliminate it.